# A public Docker Hub repo can be pulled but cannot be searched

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I created a public repo at Docker Hub 2 days ago. The repo can be pulled via Docker CLI, but it cannot be searched either in Docker Hub or via `docker search` CLI command. How come?

The concerned repo is `raptorkwok/minergate-cli`, and Docker Hub said the repo is built successfully.

Docker Hub link: [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/raptorkwok/minergate-cli)

Comment: I new a repo just now, use `docker search atline` to find mine, I also could not find the new repo. I guess there is some cache for `docker search`, maybe wait several days to have a look again?

Comment: I already waited for more than 1 day...

Comment: I use the free account, so I don't think any limit here unless docker hub change any policy. My last updated repo is 3 month ago, it could be searched, so I can't tell the information how long it will be refreshed...

Comment: I suggest you to ask this in https://forums.docker.com/, looks like more official guy there...

Comment: Some users are having the [same issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-image-search-not-updating/101130)